# CSS Plus - Uncaught ReferenceError: CodeMirror is not defined

Tags: jquery, codemirror

I've searched Google and these forums without luck. Here's my code where the error appears to be originating. Digging around in the source file is no help. This is installed on a Multi-Site WordPress and works with posts etc in admin area. All the sites are throwing this error when in post etc.

```
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(

                document.getElementById("code"), {  

                    lineNumbers: true,

                    mode: "text/x-scss", 

                    theme: "solarized light", 

                    lineWrapping: true,  

                    onCursorActivity: function() {    

                        editor.setLineClass(hlLine, null, null);    

                        hlLine = editor.setLineClass(editor.getCursor().line, null, "activeline");  }

                    });

              var hlLine = editor.addLineClass(0, "background", "activeline");

                editor.on("cursorActivity", function() {

                    var cur = editor.getLineHandle(editor.getCursor().line);

                        if (cur != hlLine) {

                            editor.removeLineClass(hlLine, "background", "activeline");

                            hlLine = editor.addLineClass(cur, "background", "activeline");

                        }

                    });

              var number = jQuery(".CodeMirror-wrap").length;

              if(number > 1){

                jQuery(".CodeMirror-wrap").hide();

                jQuery(".CodeMirror-wrap:first").show();

              }
```

[CSS Plus WordPress plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/css-plus/)

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am facing a similar issue and I have posted it here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69430941/7584240 If you get a chance can you please have a look and provide some resolution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include CodeMirror library in your site before this code is executed along with css plugin. Head over to http://codemirror.net/doc/compress.html and select core library, css mode and active line plugin.

You would also need to include  https://codemirror.net/lib/codemirror.css along with your stylesheets.

Comment: I followed your directions without luck. I ended up disabling the codemirror  in favor of getting back to work. I'll dig into it later. I appreciate your feedback.

Comment: I am facing a similar issue and I have posted it here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69430941/7584240 If you get a chance can you please have a look and provide some resolution.